# ORACLE - SQL Server interaction

Tags: sql-server, oracle, datetime

I created a dblink in oracle for my sql server db.
I created a view in ORACLE that selects the rows from sql server table.

```
CREATE VIEW V_SQLSERVERTBL("PK", "DateTimeDataRecorded", "FileModTime") 
AS 
  SELECT "PK",
         "TimeDataRecorded",
         "FileModTime"
  FROM  "mySQLServerTable"@DBLINK_sqlservertbl;
```

If I look into my sql server table: `mySQLServerTable`

```
PK (int, not null)
TimeDataRecorded (datetime, null)
FileModTime (datetime, null)
```

Then, why does my oracle view: V_SQLSERVERTBL
show:

```
PK                  NUMBER(10)
TimeDataRecorded    DATE
FileModTime         DATE
```

Why do I end up with DATE and not DATETIME format?

I need it to be DATETIME format.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You're asking if someone knows how to fix this without explaining what the problem is. Please provide more detail explaining your issue.

Comment: Oracle's [`DATE` data type includes a time component](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00202), down to seconds. Is this really a problem - do you need the fractional seconds precision from [SQL Server's `DATETIME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx), or is seconds good enough?

Comment: The Database Gateway for SQL Server User's Guide's [data type conversion appendix](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/gateways.112/e12069/apa.htm) might be of interest as well, though it doesn't look like you're using that.

Comment: you can also use timestamp. to include time factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'I solved my problem by changed my CREATE VIEW:

```
CREATE VIEW V_SQLSERVERTBL("PK", "DateTimeDataRecorded", "FileModTime") 
AS 
  SELECT "PK",
         to_char("TimeDataRecorded",''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS''), 
         to_char("FileModTime",''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'')
  FROM  "mySQLServerTable"@DBLINK_sqlservertbl;
```

So it preserves time part.

Comment: It preserved the time part anyway - as I said before, `DATE` does include the time and you're truncating the fractional seconds this way too. The second doc I linked too also said that only fractional seconds are lost in translation. You just have an unwieldy text representation of the date now, which will be harder to work with.

Comment: @Alex Poole- How do I make it then appear as datetime in my view?

Comment: With your original view in the question? It is a `DATE`, which includes a time; there is no `DATETIME` in Oracle. You can see the time from your original view with `select to_char(TimeDataRecorded, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from v_sqlservertbl;`.

Comment: Also just noticed that the version in your answer is storing the 12-hour-clock time with no AM/PM marker; so you have no way of telling if a given record is in the morning or the afternoon...

Comment: Yea... I just noticed that I pasted wrong format. Thanks @Alex Poole